# What's the refresh rate/sampling rate for the sudden motion sensor?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware

I like using my macbook pro's sudden motion sensors as an accelerometer for small at-home experiments. There are applications such as [Seismac](http://seismac.en.softonic.com/mac) that already let you do this.

I'm now writing one myself for my own purposes, but I couldn't find the sampling rate/refresh rate for the motion sensors. This information is critical if you need to reconstruct the 3D path accurately. Does anyone know where I can find this information?

Answer (score 2):

The refresh rate of the sudden motion sensor is variable.

The supported bandwith depends on the hardware used; so you have to do some more research on the specific motion sensor used in your model. I've searched [ifixit](http://www.ifixit.com) without much success.

---

According to SeisMac the motion sensor used in the *first* Macbook Pro is the **KXM-52**. The specifications state the bandwidth depends on the axis:

> - x, y axis: 0 to 3000 Hz
> - z axis: 0 to 1500 Hz

[[source: KXM-52 tech specs](http://akizukidenshi.com/download/KXM-52.pdf)]

SeisMac itself only allows to set refresh rates between [10-500 Hz in its preferences](http://www.suitable.com/tools/SeisMacHelp/preferences.html).